Looking for a time travel short story about a woman who makes small changes
Looking for a time travel short story a woman gets recruited into a time travel secret agency when a man asks her a question and instead of a trite answer she gives a thoughtful response. They end up working for an idealogue trying to force history to go a certain way but they keep failing. At the end we see the woman making small changes in the past with the implication that they matter more than the grand political schemes from before.

You can accept your own answer :)

Found it, Game of Chance by Carrie Vaughn.

Later, looking over the village, she reached for her tin box and drew out a sugar cube that had been soaked in brandy. Crumbling it and licking her fingers, she lifted a bit of earth, which made a small girl trip harmlessly four steps before she would have stumbled and fallen into a cook fire. Years later, after the girl had grown up to be the kind of revolutionary leader who saves the world, she would say she had a guardian angel.

I originally read it in the
Unfettered anthology.
